# Fillna on all rows excluding last

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, fillna

let's say I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, 5, 2, np.nan, 3], 'B': [np.nan, 4, np.nan, 5, np.nan], 'C': [np.nan, 4, 3, 2, 1]})

     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  5.0  4.0  4.0
2  2.0  NaN  3.0
3  NaN  5.0  2.0
4  3.0  NaN  1.0
```

I want to apply fillna (ffill) on all rows excluding the last one.
This is the expected output:

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  5.0  4.0  4.0
2  2.0  4.0  3.0
3  2.0  5.0  2.0
4  3.0  NaN  1.0
```

The following code doesn't work:

```
df.drop(df.tail(1).index).fillna(method="ffill",inplace=True)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `iloc` assignment with `ffill`, `iloc` to get all rows before the last row and assign it to the ffill of `df`:

```
df.iloc[:-1] = df.iloc[:-1].ffill()
```

---

```
df
```

---

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  5.0  4.0  4.0
2  2.0  4.0  3.0
3  2.0  5.0  2.0
4  3.0  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: The first one raises the follwoing ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,3) into shape (4,3) . The second one works fine though. Thanks

Comment: @younggotti Edited my answer and removed the first one! Remember to accept when the clock is ready :)